# Should I encapsulate my javascript library?

Tags: javascript

I have about 600 lines of javascript that performs ajax calls, dom manipulation, test processing, and other things.

I want to make it a library that others can use.

What are the steps to doing this?

My first thought was to encapsulate the entire library in the module pattern.  Someone suggested this earlier to help with a www.jshint.com issue.

But I thought it might be a good idea in general.

Should I encapsulate my entire library?

- Should I use the module pattern?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Information Hiding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding) is an old and well known way to make code safer and more modularized. Its one of the basic principles behind many awesome things like [Abstract Data Types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_types) and [Object Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)

---

(And yes, local variables and the module pattern are the only way to hide code in Javascript)

```
var MyModule = (function(){
    //variables in the wrapper function are local and
    // can't be seen elsewhere

    var my_var;

    function my_private_implementation_function(){ ... }

    function my_api_function(){
    }

    //return public functions
    return {
       my_api_function: my_api_function
    };
}()); //immediatelly run the module code
      //and set MyModule to the return value

//Now we can use things exported from the module

MyModule.my_api_function();

//but we can't access the prvate stuff

MyModule.my_var; //can't do this
```

Comment: Can you recommend a simple way to do this....var my_lib = {/*all code */}, perhaps

Comment: The module pattern goes more like `var Module = (function(){ ... all the code ... return an_object_containing_the_public_functions;  }());`

Comment: isn't that effectively just a singleton

Comment: @Esailija it depends on how you implement it. You can return an object that can be used as a constructor for many objects, or effectively return a singleton

Comment: @Esailija e.g. var NotSingleton = (funciton(){ var entity = function(){}; return entity; })();
var Singleton  = (funciton(){ var entity = function(){}; return new entity; })();

Comment: @Matt yes I realize you can return a constructor function, but how the module pattern is usually used (see missingno's edit) is effectively a renamed singleton pattern. You cannot make a "Class" with real hidden variables unless you are willing to accept a significant memory use increase. Not that real hidden variables are needed.

Comment: @Esailija What significant memory overhead?

Comment: @Esailija: Lets not get into a [semantic argument](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ClosuresAndObjectsAreEquivalent) here, OK?

Comment: @Matt, look at these two pages. One is using real hidden variable pattern, while the other is using real prototypes but pseudo hidden variables. In the first one, my javascript memory shoots instantly to 30MB, while in the second one it's 10MB. [hidden](http://jsfiddle.net/KYT6X/) [pseudo-hidden](http://jsfiddle.net/KYT6X/1/)

Comment: @Esailija: Are you going to have to have 10000 instances of your AJAX module then? Also, closures being ineficient in Javascript is just a side effect of current implementations not optimizing them (since functions are theoretically mutable so sharing the closures can be tricky)

Comment: I am utterly confused...can I just use var my_lib={} to not clutter the global namse-space for now...Later I can try and use something more complex

Comment: @missingno, I have lots of stuff to say, have time to chat?

Comment: @stack.user.0: if you ca get away with var my_lib = {...} then thats fine. It has the limitation of forcing all functions and variables to be public but it is fine if you don't mind that. (I suggested the module pattern version because since it is more general it is more of a "fire and forget" solution)

Comment: @Esailija I'd be up for a chat, if you don't mind my picking your brain on the topic.  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5072/javascript-namespacing

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you'd encapsulate the code, how you would expose it to the DOM, interact with it or any of those things is fully dependent on the way you would want to use it and of the context in which you would use it.
Coding patterns all serve their own unique purpose so pick a pattern because of what it provides to you, for instance in coding ease or performance or variable exposure.
So if you'd ask me, don't use a pattern because you should use a pattern, but because it does what you want it to do best.

Besides that i would advise encapsulation (if you're talking about wrapping your code in a closure) to not clutter the global object and thus avoid variable collisions which make your code more reliable since there's less risk of bugs.

Hope it helps PM5544...

Comment: would this work for starters var my_lib = {/*my code */}; to not clutter the global namespace?

Comment: That would indeed only make one blobal variable, but if you would like to keep the global vars to a absolute minimum you could wrap your code in a closure like:
(function(){
   // lib code here
})()

but that would also mean that "the outside" would have no way of getting into the scope of the closure.