# How should I encapsulate my library?

Tags: javascript

I am going to go with this possibly

```
var my_lib = 
  {
  /*
  my_code
  */
  }
```

as a way to not clutter the global name space.  Is this OK?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I encapsulate my javascript library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157898/should-i-encapsulate-my-javascript-library)

Comment: You can edit the other question to add extra information instead of splitting efferts on a new question.

Comment: Asking if "Should I encapsulate" is completely different from asking "How should I encapsulate". And that difference may translate in different answers in this question that you dont get in the other. As such, I believe these questions complement each other and are not duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function (global) {
 /* my code */

 global["someName"] = someObject;

})(window);
```

Comment: @stack.user.0 to minimize scope. So all your variables are in local scope rather then global scope.

Comment: So that any local variables you create inside there, will not be cluttered to global scope. When your script starts naked, any `var` you create will be in global scope, which is why you wanna go inside that self executing function asap :)

Comment: @stack.user.0 no, because either a object literal doesn't allow you to run code, or a block doesn't have block scoping

Comment: O.K. Sorry I'm so dense...what does (window) do...also I've seen an implementation of this were (window) was inside the previos ')'  Was this a typo...I googled module pattern..but I'm getting conflicting info.

Answer (score 0):

That's fine, however `var` will limit its scope. You might also want to wrap it in a closure as well.

Comment: will other things call your library?

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to accomplish it. I ran into this article by kangax in the past: http://perfectionkills.com/unnecessarily-comprehensive-look-into-a-rather-insignificant-issue-of-global-objects-creation/

which walks you through different approaches. I think this is the best article on the topic.