# Is window.onload considered a global variable can I put it in my module pattern?

Tags: javascript

I'm refactoring about 600 lines of javascript into the module pattern.  Here is a start from previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158557/how-should-i-encapsulate-my-library): 
I undertand the concept of anonymous methods...and sefl-executing....but not the scoping concepts...i.e. what global and window do.

```
window.onload=initialize_page;

(function (global) {  
 global['test'] = 'test'; 

function initialize_page()
  {
  /* fill  here */
  }

})(window);
```

Can I put window.onload=initialize_page into my module pattern?  Or does it need to be put outside of it?  Can someone explain how the access works?

EDIT 1: per Answer

```
(function () {  

addEventListener('load', initialize_page);

function initialize_page()
  {
  alert ("hi");
  }

})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a global. Don't touch it like that, you'll overwrite any other code that tries to assign load handlers.

Use `addEventListener` (or `attachEvent` for old IE) instead. There are plenty of [libraries](http://microjs.com/#events) that abstract the functionality.

Comment: can you elaborate...'don't touch it like that', do you meant do not assign it directly...use addEventListener....

Comment: The methods are [well documented](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&biw=1097&bih=683&q=addEventListener&oq=addEve&aq=0p&aqi=p-p1g8g-s1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=1534l5372l0l6319l17l16l5l1l2l0l385l1415l4.5.0.1l10l0)

Comment: addEventListener() registers a single event listener on a single target. The event target may be a single node in a document, the document itself, a window, or an XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: ...sorry bo be dense..but what is window.onload? It is not a node, the document, a window, or an XMLHttpRequest.  So is is applicable, what am I missing?

Comment: I thought it was an object property?

Comment: You seem to have expanded on your initial comment since I replied to it (fear the edit window!). The second half of the second sentence of my answer explains why. The second paragraph very clearly stats that I do mean use `addEventListener`.

Comment: Practically everything is an object property. `addEventListener('load', function () { alert('123'); });` works just fine in the 10 second test I just ran.

Comment: thank...I'm updating my code..as you mention this is better practice....can you elaborate on why this is better than assigning window.onload

Comment: Because overwriting onload events from other modules is rude, and having your own onload events overwritten by other modules will break your code.

Comment: O.K I updated my question with the EDIT heading to reflect the changes.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but I think `window.onload` is a function that gets called, so you reset it to be another function (that you created). You're using it as a macro there. Since `initialize_page` does not exist when you passed it, it will probably get passed to `window.onload` as `null`.

Comment: window.onload is not a function...it is a property of the window object...it points to a function that is called when the "page" loads/reloads...I think

Comment: @stack.user.0 sorry, I stopped distinguishing between values and pointers when I moved from C to JS. Yes, you can overwrite the property with a different function (pointer), but only if the function (pointer) exists. \

Comment: @stack.user.0 C is a wonderful language (I don't actually mean that) but I prefer the productivity and and freedom of JS.